# How to achieve something like width : max-content + 5rem in css?

Tags: css, angular

I have a dropdown component in which I have expandable items. I want the width to be max-content plus 5 rem. so when let's say the width of the content is 6 rem, I want the actual width to be 11 rem. When the content becomes 10rem, I want the dropdown width to be 15rem.

I want to achieve something like `width :  max-content + 5 rem;` How do I do this?

Comment: by adding some padding equal to 5rem ?

Comment: Already tried that and that does not work, reason being padding will be added at rendering, but max content is calculated on the fly

Comment: Basically, you can't.

Answer (score -1):

## Maybe this can help

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but technically, you can do this by using **`calc()`** and **`var()`** functions in **CSS3**. Firstly, you need to set the variable in **`root`** section **(*you can name it what you want*)**, and then use it with **`var()`**. The **`calc()`** is used, to calculate, as its name says. It can be used like: **`calc(100px + 100px)`** and so on...

### Here's the sample:

**HTML**

```
<div>
  Some text... /* This is optional */
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
:root {
  --max-width: 10em;
}

div {
  width: calc(var(--max-width) + 5em);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbjnq0kw/) example

Comment: But I donot know what the width of my max-content will be. how do i add 5 rem to the max content width at any point of time?

Comment: @ShrikanthPS Basically, if you set the variable at the root in CSS, and then apply to an actual `max-width` property, you could always change the max-width, by changing the value of the `max-width` variable. Example: `:root { --max-width: 10rem; } div { max-width: var(--max-width)}` **if you change the value of the variable, it'll change the properties value**. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: `max-content` is determined dynamically. This answer assumes it's a known static value, which it isn't.